# VisualState not working when adding control programmatically

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I have custom toolbar which can show "busy" state as an animated clock. When I add this animated clock control via XAML (top portion) it works fine, I can see spinning arrows. When I add control programmatically - it doesn't "spin"

[image]

This is style for button:

```
<Style TargetType="controls:IdattToolbarBusy">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:IdattToolbarBusy">
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation x:Name="minutesArrowAnimation" 
                                              Storyboard.TargetName="minutesArrowTransform" 
                                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" 
                                              Duration="0:0:2" RepeatBehavior="Forever" To="360" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation x:Name="hoursArrowAnimation" 
                                              Storyboard.TargetName="hoursArrowTransform" 
                                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" 
                                              Duration="0:0:3" RepeatBehavior="Forever" To="360" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <StackPanel x:Name="PART_Container" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5">
                            <Image Source="/IDATT.Infrastructure.SL;component/Images/img_status_busy.png" x:Name="PART_IconImage" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                            <TextBlock x:Name="PART_CaptionTextBlock" FontSize="9" Padding="2,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{TemplateBinding Caption}" />
                        </StackPanel>

                        <Rectangle x:Name="minutesHand" Fill="#FFFF0000" Height="6" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                          Margin="16, 9, 0, 0"  RenderTransformOrigin="0.45,1.34" 
                          Stroke="#FF000000" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1" >
                            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                <RotateTransform x:Name="minutesArrowTransform"/>
                            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="hoursHand" Fill="#FFFF0000" Height="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                          Margin="16, 12, 0, 0"  RenderTransformOrigin="0.45,1.34" 
                          Stroke="#FF000000" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="2" >
                            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                <RotateTransform x:Name="hoursArrowTransform"/>
                            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        </Rectangle>

                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

When I use code to add control - it looks like this:

```
var busyIndicator = new IdattToolbarBusy { Caption = "Busy" };
                this.StatusStackPanel.Children.Add(busyIndicator);
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(busyIndicator, "Normal", true);
```

Last line of code was added by me trying to fix an issue, but it still don't work. When control was initially created everything was working fine, it was in Silverlight 4. Now we upgraded to SL 5 and it's not spinning.

I think it's because it doesn't trigger "Normal" state for some reason but can't figure out how to fix it..

EDIT:

This is code for busy Indicator:

```
public class IdattToolbarBusy : IdattToolbarButton
{
    public IdattToolbarBusy()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(IdattToolbarBusy);
        var aa = VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(this);
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Normal", true);
    }
}
```

I placed this line of code for VisualStateManager and it doesn't work. But.. `aa` variable has 0 state groups. So, it seems like XAML-based insertion works but in code VSM doesn't see my group..

Comment: If instead of adding it, you toggle its visibility instead, do you get the same result? There's a few other ways of doing what you want that personally I would have opted for alternatively, and we could still swap it with, but I'm curious about the difference here.

Comment: Chris, toolbar is based of ContentControl and top one (animated) clock added to toolbar.items and it works. Then I have StackPanel inside and add second one  (non-working) to this StackPanel programmaticaly. There is no way to easy test what you propose. Do you have any idea on why it doesn't work? I'm posting edit to question to give more details on this busyButton...

Comment: I think the problem may be that the control has not been added to the visual tree yet and so VSM can't find it. For aa, you are trying to get the states on the control (this) but they are actually in the child grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think (guessing) that Rob Jacobs is correct -- I would try adding the `GoToState` call inside the "OnApplyTemplate", or on "Loaded".

```
public class IdattToolbarBusy : IdattToolbarButton
{
    public IdattToolbarBusy()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(IdattToolbarBusy);
        var aa = VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(this);
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Normal", true);
    }
}
```

If that doesn't work ... are you sure that "Normal" isn't the default state for controls, and therefore is not being updated when you try to change it?  It seems proper that "Normal" should be reserved for the default control state, and you should rename your state to "Busy" or something else.

Comment: That was it. Using OnApplyTemplate works. Normal is default state, but for some reason it's not auto-started in all cases.